how to make a render image as a circle
Hi I want to make a round image in the camera but all I can find is how to do it in older versions of blender. I tried to repeat as there but I can't, who can tell me how to do it.

Digital images are always rectangular. Please edit the question and clarify what you mean by "round image". Providing example images might be helpful. It's not possible to answer this question the way it is currently written.

I assume you're talking about a circular mask which you do in Blender's compositor nowadays. This is Blender's manual section on the Elipse Mask.

What do you mean by round image? Mirror Ball images? Then go to the camera settings, set it to Panoramic and choose Mirror Ball. But you will not see the mirror ball image in EEVEE, it only works in Cycles and it only shows in Rendered view, not in Material Preview, Solid or Wireframe.
